# Windows is waiting some programs to close

Tags: windows, shutdown

I'm using windows 8.1 64bit and something just happend.
When I try to shut my pc down, it says that a specific program is running, and it wont shut down. The problem is that I don't want that program to run, but on the shutdown screen, i can only see its icon, so I have no idea whitch program is that. 
Many thanks

Comment: Did you click _Force Shutdown_? You could also use **Task Manager** to find the running tasks and processes and track down the offending program.

Comment: What does its icon look like? Is it the generic program icon (depicting empty program window in 3D view) or something else?

Comment: yes i clicked, but i dont want to, that is my problem, if i click to the shutdown button then i want my pc off, not clicking buttons after i clicked once.
its a simple windows exe file

Comment: This is for Windows Vista but it should help you, procedure is same for both I guess, try it and let us know if it works. You have to open registry editor and modify waiting time for services to finish before shutdown. [Here is the instruction at Microsoft Answers](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-performance/programs-will-not-close-normally-at-shutdown/39bc83ef-dde7-4fe1-aacb-f27559dc0d01)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing Registry modification as @swapna mentioned. I would suggest you to find out what program running background and fix it once and for all

Goto MsConfig.exe by typing this on RUN -> msconfig

and then in the StartUp section you can find all the running programs, 1st uncheck all and restart 1st to take effect. then again Restart for testing. if everything ok you're ok :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would start Windows 8.1 in Safe Mode (here you have only the necessary processes running). After 5 or 6 minutes I would try to shut it down, if it is shutting down normally I would than proceed and start up normally Windows 8.1 and open the Task Manager and check all the processes that are running, one of these processes running is the problem. I guess a third party program is blocking your PC from shutting down normally. Check also the startup tab in the Task Manager, disable the processes you do not need to start with the OS.

Comment: thank you guys, if i have time, i'll try it all. thanks again

Comment: @user283085 don't forget to +1 the post